# SharePoint 2013 Event Receiver not firing on programmatic upload

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint Document Library Template in my Visual Studio 2012 Solution which is just a plain document library with

> Type="24442"

to distinguish it for the eventreceiver. The eventreceiver reacts to ItemAdded and ItemUpdated for

> ListTemplateId="24442"

As long as I work with the library through the SharePoint WebInterface the eventreceiver reacts and fires as expected. The moment I try to use a c# program to put the file into the library with

```
list.RootFolder.Files.Add(...)
```

The eventreceiver doesn't fire. The file remains in the library and is not processed.
Is there a reason for this behaviour? Even the following code doesn't trigger the eventreceiver:

```
var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(...);
file.Update();
```

I already tried to place a Thread.Sleep after these calls but no effect on raising the event. (This was suggested on a website regarding a similar problem)

--- UPDATE ---

Here's the code I use to upload into the document library:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLocation))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl(Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLocation);
    if (list != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opening folder({0}) and copy files...", Properties.Settings.Default.SourceFolder);
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.SourceFolder))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing file({0})...", file);

                var spfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file), File.ReadAllBytes(file), true);
                //spfile.Update();
                spfile.Item.Update();
                Console.WriteLine("Upload succeeded!");

                //File.Delete(file);
                Console.WriteLine("Moving file to target location ({0})...", Properties.Settings.Default.TargetFileLocation);

                File.Move(file, Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.TargetFileLocation, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm") + Path.GetExtension(file)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy failed\n{0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does file.Item.Update() fire event receiver?

Comment: Maybe you disable event firing somewhere in your code before uploading file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.eventfiringenabled.aspx

Comment: I'll try the Item.Update(), probably this works.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets: The property you mention is part of the EventReceiverBase Class and can only be accessed within the Eventreceiver itself. Usually used if you work with files in a library and want to avoid other workflows to start.

Comment: I know, but i do not see your full code - maybe you uploading document to document library from other event receiver, i do not know that.

Comment: I tried the Item.Update() and still no luck. In the meantime I abandoned the library template and used the common document library and changed the Receivers settings to `ListUrl="/IncomingLibrary"`. Once again it works fine when uploading manually but doesn't fire when I use a program to do it.